# How to cause an update of model to trigger a update in another controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

View Controller A has access to a model and can mutate the model. View Controller B displays the model. I want when View Controller A updates the model, a method to be triggered in View Controller B such that the view is updated. Is there a standard way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

In the didset of this variable you can post a notification and the other controller can register for this notification. (We can do it more neatly depending on the requirement.)

Comment: My model can be represented as either a class or struct. If its a struct, the two controllers can't share the same reference. Should I pass the struct over the notification? Or if it's a class, then how can you add a didSet? (since there doesn't seem to be a similar way of marking "mutating" for classes) Or should the didSet be created inside the model, rather than in the view controller that owns it?

Comment: if you want to notify on any sub property change then you will have to use structs but then it will not share as you said but in class you will have to write in every properties didSet.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your model object an Objective-C object (`@objc`) then you can use KVO (key-value observering) to observe changes to it. If you do that then any object that's observing a property of the model will get notified when that property changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do this.

Have whatever model you use, class or struct, implement a protocol that can be be used by view-controller B.  view-controller B should not care what the model is, only that it conforms to the protocol it needs to extract the data it needs.

When view-controller A manipulates the model,  post a notification with a reference to the model as an instance of the protocol, in the userInfo dictionary.  view-controller B, subscribes to the notification and when triggered, extracts the reference from the userInfo and then gets the data it needs via the common protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to communicate between 2 view controllers is Protocol. Define a protocol, such as:

```
protocol ViewControllerAModelProtocol: class {
    func viewControllerAModelDidUpdate()
}
```

In ViewControllerA, define a delegate type:

```
weak var updatedProtocol: viewControllerAModelDidUpdate?
```

When the model is updated and call:

```
updatedProtocol?.viewControllerAModelDidUpdate()
```

In ViewControllerB, implement the protocol:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, ViewControllerAModelProtocol {

    func viewControllerAModelDidUpdate() {
        // reloadData()
    }

}
```

If ViewControllerB is presented or showed by ViewControllerA, set A's updatedProtocol to B:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let b = segue.destination as? ViewControllerAModelProtocol {
        self.updatedProtocol = b
    }

}
```